# python pandas time series count number of previous matches

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate-functions

**Given:**

```
applications = pd.DataFrame({'application_id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                   'date': ['2015-01-05', '2015-01-06', '2015-01-07', '2015- 01-08', '2015-01-09'],
                    'client_employer': ['company A', 'company B', 'company C', 'company A', 'company B'],
                    'client_name': ['Bill', 'John', 'Steve', 'Bill', 'Alex']})
```

**Table:**

```
         date  client_employer client_name 
   0  2015-01-05 company A       John 
   1  2015-01-06 company B       Bill
   2  2015-01-07 company B       Bill
   3  2015-01-08 company A       Sarah
   4  2015-01-09 company B       Alex
   5  2015-01-10 company B       Brian
```

How many different people with the same employer do we have in past? NO LOOPS

**Desired output:**

```
       date  client_employer client_name  employers_count
 0  2015-01-05 company A       John         0
 1  2015-01-06 company B       Bill         0
 2  2015-01-07 company B       Bill         0
 3  2015-01-08 company A       Sarah        1
 4  2015-01-09 company B       Alex         1
 5  2015-01-10 company B       Brian        2
```

## Suggestion doesn't work correctly:

```
applications = pd.DataFrame({'application_id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                       'date': ['2015-01-05', '2015-01-06', '2015-01-07', '2015-01-08', '2015-01-09', '2015-01-10'],
                        'client_employer': ['company B', 'company B', 'company B', 'company B', 'company B', 'company B'],
                        'client_name': ['Bill', 'John', 'Steve', 'Bill', 'Alex', 'Bill'],
                        'cnt_desired': [0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]})

emp_count = applications.groupby(['client_employer'])['client_name'].transform(lambda x: x.map(dict(zip(x.unique(),np.arange(len(x.unique()))))))
applications['cnt'] = emp_count

   application_id         date client_employer client_name  cnt_desired  cnt
0               1   2015-01-05       company B        Bill            0    0
1               2   2015-01-06       company B        John            1    1
2               3   2015-01-07       company B       Steve            2    2
3               4   2015-01-08       company B        Bill            2    0
4               5   2015-01-09       company B        Alex            3    3
5               6   2015-01-10       company B        Bill            3    0
```

Comment: How you edited my code and table?

Comment: I am actually didn't understand the problem could you please explain it in a broad way so that I can give you the right solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First use `groupby` on `client_employer` then access `client_name` column and transform the column  using `map` created based on `dict` of `client_name` unique values as keys and `range` of number of unique values as values:

```
df['employers_count'] = df.groupby(['client_employer'])['client_name'].transform(lambda x: x.map(dict(zip(x.unique(),range(x.nunique())))))

         date client_employer client_name  employers_count
0  2015-01-05       company A       John                 0
1  2015-01-06       company B        Bill                0
2  2015-01-07       company B        Bill                0
3  2015-01-08       company A       Sarah                1
4  2015-01-09       company B        Alex                1
5  2015-01-10       company B       Brian                2
```